# With the Swift Network Framework, how can I make IPv4Address and IPv6Address conform to Codable?

Tags: swift, network-programming

The Swift Network Framework includes the Structs `IPv4Address` and `IPv6Address`.  They are used with `NWEndpoints` for network connections.  The `IPv6Address` Struct also useful for validating `IPv6` address syntax and implementing shortening rules.

How can I make `IPv4Address` and `IPv6Address` conform to Codable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create your own IPv4AddressDecodingError. You can throw a `DecodingError` using its `dataCorruptedError` method. Btw there is no need to create a `CodingKeys` enumeration for a single value:

You can also create a protocol that conforms to `RawRepresentable & Codable` and constrain `RawValue` to `Codable`. This way you can create generic encoder and decoder methods for both ip addresses:

```
import Network
public protocol RawRepresentableCodableProtocol: RawRepresentable & Codable
                                                 where Self.RawValue: Codable { }
```

---

```
public extension RawRepresentableCodableProtocol {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let rawValue = try container.decode(RawValue.self)
        guard let object = Self(rawValue: rawValue) else {
            throw DecodingError
                .dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid rawValue data: \(rawValue)")
        }
        self = object
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(rawValue)
    }
}
```

---

Now we can extend `RawRepresentableCodableProtocol` constraining `Self` to `IPAddress` protocol and provide a fallible rawValue data initializer:

```
public extension RawRepresentableCodableProtocol where Self: IPAddress {
     init?(rawValue: Data) {
        guard let object = Self(rawValue, nil) else { return nil }
        self = object
    }
}
```

---

```
extension IPv4Address: RawRepresentableCodableProtocol { }
extension IPv6Address: RawRepresentableCodableProtocol { }
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let ipv4 = IPv4Address("1.2.33.44")!                                         // 1.2.33.44
let dataIPv4 = try JSONEncoder().encode(ipv4)                                // 10 bytes
let loadedIPv4 = try JSONDecoder().decode(IPv4Address.self, from: dataIPv4)  // 1.2.33.44

let ipv6 = IPv6Address("2001:db8::35:44")!                                   // 2001:db8::35:44
let dataIPv6 = try JSONEncoder().encode(ipv6)                                // 26 bytes
let loadedIPv6 = try JSONDecoder().decode(IPv6Address.self, from: dataIPv6)  // 2001:db8::35:44
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the IPv4Address.rawValue or IPv6Address.rawValue field to get the IPv4 or IPv6 address in a Data() structure.  Then encode the Data.

When decoding, you can use the Data to initialize the address, handling the failable initializer case.

It is also possible to use the IPv6Address.description or IPv6Address.debugDescription to do an encode, but that is not recommended because those descriptions may change format in the future (thx Martin R).

```
import Foundation
import Network

extension IPv6Address: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ipv6Data
    }
    enum IPv6AddressDecodingError: Error {
        case decoding(String)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let addressData = self.rawValue
        try container.encode(addressData, forKey: .ipv6Data)
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let addressData = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .ipv6Data)
        guard let ipv6Address = IPv6Address(addressData) else {
            throw IPv6AddressDecodingError.decoding("unable to decode IPv6 address from \(values)")
        }
        self = ipv6Address
    }
}
```

IPv4Address is essentially identical:

```
import Foundation
import Network

extension IPv4Address: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ipv4Data
    }
    enum IPv4AddressDecodingError: Error {
        case decoding(String)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let addressData = self.rawValue
        try container.encode(addressData, forKey: .ipv4Data)
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let addressData = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .ipv4Data)
        guard let ipv4Address = IPv4Address(addressData) else {
            throw IPv4AddressDecodingError.decoding("unable to decode IPv4 address from \(values)")
        }
        self = ipv4Address
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a fragile approach. `debugDescription` is a *“representation of the string that is suitable for debugging.”* Its format is undocumented and can change at any time in the future.

Comment: Good to know.  Changed to use description.  Even there the standard library says "Using this property directly is discouraged."  But it's reassuring that the description is the text of the IPv4 or IPv6 address.  I'm happy to accept alternative answers since encoding IPv4Address and IPv6Address structs to Codable is critical to a project I'm working on.

Comment: description might be problematic as well, here is an example: Printing a Data value used to print a hex dump of the bytes. Later it was changed to print just “nnn bytes”.

Comment: @MartinR Encoding using rawValue as Data is tested and successful. Updated answers with the new code. Also updated in my current project. Thanks!